# compare two array base on first array then return value who have match even not exact

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

hello is there a way that i can filter my array base on second array with have match even not exact? on my case is something like this

first = [Mon Sep 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), Tue Sep 10 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), Wed Sep 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), Thu Sep 12 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), Fri Sep 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)];

second = ["Mon", "Wed", "Fri"];

what i need is return of array from my first that have match even ?

need result is :

first = [Mon Sep 09 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), Wed Sep 11 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time), Fri Sep 13 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern Standard Time)];

Comment: i thing your firts array is type Date[] and next is string[], then `arr1.filter(d => arr2.includes(fnDay(d.getDay())))` should do it where fnDay will return Mon for 0 Tue for 1 and so on, or you could hook this fn from momentjs

Comment: hello im new to javascript but does .include means? looking for exact string?

Comment: yes it will try to look at exact match. But tell me your first array how did you construct it?

Comment: it was first a date range who had a start and end value then i use a function to run through of it to get each day of the day that inside of range , then now i have a second array that contain days of a week, i need an idea on how to filter my first array to the second one

Comment: yup so what you see in the first array is a array of javascript Date objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple solution just replace arr1 with your array1 the date array and needleArray with your second array

```js
// You can construct all the days of week array
var daysArray = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

// your array 1 I am just mocking it for the solution to work
var arr1 = [new Date('09/05/2019'), new Date('09/08/2019'), new Date('09/02/2019')];


var needleArray = ['Mon', 'Wed', 'Fri']


var filteredArray = arr1.filter(date => needleArray.includes(daysArray[date.getDay()]))

console.log(filteredArray)
```

Comment: whoa cant believe that it works this way , thanks men i spend lot of time with this,

Comment: ya and someone is actually downvoting as well. glad it worked for you.

Comment: heheh thanks again mate.